# Flex Mobile How to allow Automatic reorient for certain page view only

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

In my Mobile Project, i have set -> Application Setting -> **Automatic reorient = False**

Can i make only a certain page able to **reorient = True** (change from Portrait to Landscape mode). If yes how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible, however, you could always do it using rotate="90", but you'll have to code for all the possible cases.

Comment: what about the other way round, If **Automatic reorient = True** and i only make some pages **reorient = False**?

Comment: This is something that needs to be set on the Air wrapper (in the app.xml).  So, I don't think it's possible to do it at runtime.  This might not be the case with Air 3 (since it just came out), but I know with all versions of Air beforehand, it needed to be set at compile time.

Comment: I just found this link, maybe it could work: [link](http://polygeek.com/4301_air-mobile_playing-with-stage-orientation-in-mobile-air-apps)

Comment: Huh, I just learned something new.  Guess you can do it through the stage in Air. Give it a go.